# Gulp 4 unable to end after complete finish

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am using **gulp 4.0** version. I am unable to finish task at the end. It just stuck at end on console

I have following task running in series,

```
gulp.task("test", gulp.series("runUnitTests", "runApiTests"));
```

**runApitTests task**

```
gulp.task("runApiTests",
gulp.series((
        "runDevDataApiTests",
        "runQaDataApiTests"
    )
));
```

I also refer some issues on [github](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1904)

Comment: All tasks are expected to comply with [`async-done`](https://github.com/gulpjs/async-done#completion-and-error-resolution) (as per [`undertaker`'s doc](https://github.com/gulpjs/undertaker)), your problem looks like something doesn't notify its ending...

Comment: Looks like what you make sense, i need to check into that

Comment: The issue is resolve, there was mongo DB process was hanging around which was not closed on completion. So gulp 4.0 is working fine for me